# Another "how to find className"

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, package, classname

I've used the search functions and i've read and tried a lot of examples, but I can't find a solution for my problem... So, here we go:

I want to send Intents to only 1 BroadcastReceiver. Therefore I need to create a new Intent and send it to the packageName and the packageClass:

`intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, className));`

To find out packageName and className i use this code:

```
String appInfo = list.get(myPlayer).activityInfo.toString();
Log.d("TAG", "app " + appInfo);

String packageName = list.get(myPlayer).activityInfo.packageName.toString();    
Log.d("TAG", "package " + packageName);

String className = list.get(myPlayer).activityInfo.getClass().getName().toString();
Log.d("TAG", "class " + className);
```

From logcat I get following results(example for Play Music):

```
app ActivityInfo{417bd5e0 com.google.android.music.MediaButtonIntentReceiver}
package com.google.android.music
class android.content.pm.ActivityInfo
```

Isn't this strange? For some reason, I'd expect for the class log only "MediaButtonIntentReceiver" and not "android.content.pm.ActivityInfo"!!!

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're searching for `packageName` and `className` for filling ordered broadcast, I really suggest to check content of [ResolveInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ResolveInfo.html) object you're probably using

- ResolveInfo contains [ActivityInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html) object
- ActivityInfo contains [ApplicationInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html) object
- ApplicationInfo object contain what you need

so in you case, if you need to complete content of intent, I may suggest

```
    ResolveInfo ri = ... // get where you need
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
        ri.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName,
        ri.activityInfo.applicationInfo.className));
```

this should work for you case

**Edit:** in cases, you obtained ResolveInfo for specific intent, `className` should be `null`. In these cases I successfully use `ri.activityInfo.name` which returns correct `className` because `activityInfo` is for one specific activity

Comment: (upvote) I swear I glanced at the docs for a method like this... and that's the problem this is a field variable.

Comment: this is unfortunately just a another small problem of Android SDK - inconsistency like this. Instead of `getActivityInfo().getApplicationInfo().getPackageName()`, there are just a public variables :/

Comment: OMG. What a bad answer. You should not use applicationInfo!! In all cases use `activityInfo.name`

Comment: The explanation why `applicationInfo` is not the usable solution is welcome. Isn't `activityInfo` tight to the activity itself? We need here information about the app package.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put: `getClass()` doesn't do what your expect it to do.
However using what you have you can get what you want like so:

```
String appInfo = list.get(myPlayer).activityInfo.toString();
String className = appInfo.substring(appInfo.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, appInfo.length() - 1);
Log.d("TAG", "class " + className);
```

---

Notice that `packageName` is a field of ActivityInfo, not a method. While [`getClass()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) is a method, but it's a method of `Object`, from it's documentation:

> Returns the unique instance of Class that represents this object's class.

So you are asking for the name of `activityInfo`, which is (as you know know) `ActivityInfo`.

Comment: You're welcome, I adjusted my answer to remove the `}` on the end.

Answer (score 0):

It's not strange at all.  Here:

```
String className = list.get(myPlayer).activityInfo.getClass().getName().toString()
```

You're getting the class of the `ActivityInfo` object.  I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but that's why you're seeing what you're seeing.

Comment: But why don't I get the packageName of the "ActivityInfo"? 
BTW, if I remove "ActivityInfo" I get the className for "ResolveInfo"...

Comment: it should be a comment, yes, you pointed the wrong code, but still it's not an answer